# Error importing mahotas in python (missing dll file)

Tags: python, image, dll, import

I installed the mahotas library as the site says to but i keep getting the same error when i try to import the module:

```
Could not import submodules (exact error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.).

There are many reasons for this error the most common one is that you have
either not built the packages or have built (using `python setup.py build`) or
installed them (using `python setup.py install`) and then proceeded to test
mahotas **without changing the current directory**.

Try installing and then changing to another directory before importing mahotas.
```

Someone knows what i'm doing rong?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on Windows.

For that platform, I recommend you try these compiled packages: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

(I'm the author of mahotas)